# Return all values from table if one field in query string is empty and its in String format

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, sqldatasource

I have a page that list products from table based on values passed in querystring.
ex:-  abc/product.aspx/subcat=Mobile&bnd=Samsung 
Here it will display all mobile with brand Samsung 
How can i display all mobile irrespective of the brand if **bnd** is *empty or not passed* i.e only **subcat** value is passed.
I need SqlDataSource command to do the same. My current query is as shown below:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:shoppingConnectionString2 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductDetails] WHERE (([Sub_category] = @Sub_category) AND ([Brand] = @Brand OR @Brand IS NULL))" 
    onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Sub_category" QueryStringField="subcat" 
            Type="String" DefaultValue="&quot; &quot;" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Brand" QueryStringField="bnd" Type="String" 
            DefaultValue="IS NULL" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Just check the parameters out of the sql command, it will be cleaner. it will spare you from writing complex sql commands, and change your command accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string subcat = Request.QueryString["subcat"];
        string bnd = Request.QueryString["bnd"];

        string query = "SELECT * FROM [ProductDetails] WHERE ([Sub_category] = " + subcat + ")";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bnd))
        {
            query += " AND ([Brand] = " + bnd + ")";
        }                

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = query;                
    }
}
```

HTML markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:shoppingConnectionString2 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductDetails]" 
    onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

(Note the removed SelectParameters)

I've never used a SqlDataSource before, but this is similar to what I'd do for an ObjectDataSource. Would the above code work for your scenario?

**EDIT :** Please note that this method is open to SQL injection attacks, so you ought to validate/sanitize the querystring parameters first.

Comment: Wow really thanks for this and also i was not knowing that i can handle this with code-behind also. Really really thanks for this. And their is just a bit change, as my values are string so it will be '"+subcat+"'.